# Computing large nested values

Tags: functions

Is it possible to compute a value for

```
n=10^9; Nest[# + Log[#] &, 2., n]
```

for large `n`? $10^9$ seems to be the max for me - is it possible to use previous results to compute piecewise, or any other workaround?

Comment: What do you mean 10^9 is the max? Does Nest tell you it won't nest anymore? Have you tried taking the output value as the starting point and Nesting again for another 10^9 by hand? If that works it would be simple to write a function that does your calculation in chunks of 10^9.

Comment: @N.J.Evans no, I don't think it works like that

Comment: I tried 2*10^9, and it works just fine. The time to get the result seems to grow linearly with `n`. Since the computation is done with machine precision, I don't see any issues increasing `n` further, except the trivial one that it takes proportionally longer to compute.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin for $10^{10}$ I get `"Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in \
Nest[#1+Log[#1]&,2.,10000000000]."`

Comment: 10^9 is near 2^32 if we're talking order of magnitude.

Comment: Have you actually tried taking the output and feeding it back in? `a = Nest[#+Log[#]&, 2., 10^9]; b = Nest[#+Log[#]&, a, 10^9]` Because it sounds like Nest takes a 32 bit integer for the third argument.

Comment: @N.J.Evans ah, was thinking it would work exponentially, but of course not! you are right - thank you :)

Comment: @martin glad to help! I've wasted entire days on things like this. :-/

Comment: @N.J.Evans thanks - me too!

Comment: @N.J.Evans If you write something like `f[x_, r_] := Nest[# + Log[#] &, x, r]` `g[r_, times_] := 
 Fold[f[#1, #2] &, f[2., r], ConstantArray[r, times - 1]]` `{f[2., 3*10^3],
g[10^3, 3]}` I will accept :)

Comment: Interestingly, this function has a series expansion around 1 which begins like the following : `1 + 2^n (x0-1) + (2^(n-2) - 4*4^(n-2)) (x0-1)^2 +...` for initial value `x0` and `n` the nesting depth. I'm still working on the higher order terms

Comment: @Histograms Great!! I would be really gratefuol if you would post an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282284/is-it-possible-to-write-this-in-closed-form) when you are ready :)

Comment: @Histograms or here in this post if you prefer - would be really interested in how you did it too :)

Comment: @martin I can't seem to come up with a general formula for the cubic term :( but all the coefficients seem to always be divisible by a large power of 2, smaller than n. A remarkably interesting function! I was able to get the first two just by looking at the coefficients of `Series[Nest[# + Log[#] &, x, n], {x, 1, 4}]` for different `n` values. The second order term just happens to have a coefficient from [this](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+14%2C60%2C+248%2C+1008%2C+4064&sort=&language=english&go=Search) sequence.

Comment: @Histograms I see! Ingenious! Great attack on the problem - I will give it a go too - I would be really grateful if you could keep me posted if you get anywhere with it! :)

Comment: @martin So I couldn't get any further with this and I suspect the coefficients have a very complex form, but I did make this somewhat irrelevant tweet sized fractal thing out of a similar related function log(x) - x :

 `d=0.005;n=15;t=ParallelTable[If[NumericQ@#,Abs@#,0]&@Nest[(Log@#-#)&,x0+I y0,n],{x0,-1,1,d},{y0,-1,1,d}];ColorNegate@Image[Tanh[0.65*t]]`

I  think I can see Satan in there somewhere.

Comment: @Histograms nice!!! Please post as answer in MSE - *too long for a comment* sort of thing :)

Comment: @Histograms ... only if you feel it is relevant of course. Still, nice image! I'm not sure about Satan, but I think I can see batman in there ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems that `Nest` is limited to 32-bit integers for the 3rd argument. The way around this is to apply Nest to the result of the first ~2^32 Nests.  Supplying his own function using Fold, @martin suggests

```
f[x_, r_] := Nest[# + Log[#] &, x, r]; 
g[r_, times_] := Fold[f[#1, #2] &, f[2., r], ConstantArray[r, times - 1]];
 {f[2., 3*10^3], g[10^3, 3]}
```